# What does this error message mean in expss

Tags: expss

I read an SPSS file and apply labels.
library (haven)
library (expss)
nps2020 <- haven::read_spss("NPS Data_2020_28 Dec 2020.sav")
nps2020 <- add_labelled_class(nps2020)

Sometimes expss can find the variables when they actually exist.
Error message -

> TabANPSMeansNew<-nps2020%>%tab_cols(total(),AgeC,S22,S23,S25_2)%>%

- tab_cells(s28FEngen)%>%
- tab_stat_mean()%>%
- tab_pivot()
  Error in NCOL(x) :
  object 'S28.1.  On a scale of 1-5, where 1 is “not safe at all” and 5 is “extremely safe”please rate the level of safety you experienced at the “ENGEN - Forecourt” of the brands you have visited over your last five visits to petrol stations?' not found
  Variable s28Engen does exist but in this example expss can read it - what causes this?

Comment: Could you provide sample of your data? Without it is difficult to find the cause of the error.

Comment: I would like to but the data is confidential. How can I share it only with you?

Comment: You can drop sample of your data to gdemin at gmail.com. Several rows and variables from your code will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Gregory but when I was preparing an example for you everything started working correctly. A bit embarrassing but working now. Thanks for offering to look into things for me. Kind regards. Mark